# Sum of Prime Factorizations and Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, integer-partitions

If I partition an integer and get the prime factorization of each partition, is there a way to tell if my original integer was a prime? For example, given the factorization of my partitions
$$71 = (56) + (15) = (2^{3}\cdot 7^{1}) + (3^{1}\cdot 5^{1})$$

How can I find out if 71 is a prime number from these factorizations?

Comment: Do you mean $2^3\cdot 7^1$ and $3^1\cdot 5^1$ ? In this case, we know that the number cannot be divisibel by a prime less than $11$ which is here enough to prove that $71$ is prime.

Comment: This however will only work for small numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, the method only works if we have TWO summands.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a method that works for bigger numbers with more summands?

Comment: In special cases, it can work as well as in $2\cdot 3+3\cdot 5+2\cdot 5$ which actually shows that the given number is not divisible by $2,3$ or $5$. But again, we only have a very small number. This method is only good to rule out specific prime factors (if we are lucky , several at the same time). Primality tests for larger numbers work completely different.

Comment: You don't need to consider all the partitions. You only need to consider one partition. $N=(N-1)/2 + (N+1)/2$. But factoring $(N-1)/2$ and $(N+1)/2$ doesn't really say anything about the factors of $N$. Example $91=7*13=45+46=(21+24)+(18+28)$. You basically need to write $7=3+4$ and $13=6+7$ to get the useful decomposition, not $45+46$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more work than it's worth, but if you partition a number into every possible combination of two addends, and if the members of every such partition are relatively prime (i.e. no prime factor of one member of a partition occurs in the other member of that partition), then the starting number is prime.

If the starting number is not prime, say $a\cdot b$, then there will be some partition $ac,ad$ where $c+d=b$ such that the members of the partition are not coprime.

Comment: You are right about the inefficiency. Even trial division beats this method drastically. But in fact, it would be a primality test.